# Diversify 'root' and 'rooting'

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup, retag-request

Currently, [root](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/root) is a synonym to [rooting](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rooting). I want to propose separating the two:

- "rooting" concerns the process of *gaining* root access to a device, as its [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info) (including the excerpt) describes. The majority of the questions reflect that.
- "root" should be used in connection with issues involving an already *existing* root account, or being specific to *already rooted* devices.

As usual, I volunteer to sort-out (re-tag) questions accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like the suggestion. And it's even better if we have a volunteer. :)

If there are no objections and counter arguments, then the separation should get done.

Comment: [I concur](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8802434#8802434).

Comment: Whenever 'root' was separated, please give me a ping so I *immediately* set up the tag wiki(s) and excerpt(s) to make clear what-is-what, and start the re-tagging process. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Task completed: tag-wikis generated/updated, all 400+ `rooting` questions checked. Many simply lost the `rooting` tag (no relation to either root or rooting), 73 went to `root`, 307 left in `rooting`. Next I will check for all those questions we removed the `rooting` tag in the past as they didn't deal with the rooting process as such. *Long way to paradise...*